# Instagram api oauth 405 not allowed

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm try to use instagram api with `postman`.

I did a post request:

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token

```
client_id : "client_id"
client_secret : "client_secret"
grant_type : authorization_code
redirect_uri : "redirect_uri"
code : "code"
```

and resut is: 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED

What can I do for correct response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems now is working correctly. Most likely was a temporary Instagram internal issue. Instagram deleveloper's blog doesn't report anything.

Comment: Perhaps people should still be advised to follow the solutions in this thread to prevent future accidents.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can understand, this is incorrect. Our production app using POST to this endpoint just started breaking about 15 minutes ago. I tried issuing a GET to no avail. The 'Allow' header in the response does say POST, so I think this what we are intended to do, but there appears to be a problem.

Comment: Our production apps instagram auth also just started failing. It appears to be an instagram issue, even trying to auth in with their API console fails... https://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: This also just started happening to me on multiple Instagram applications. No confirmation yet, but I think Instagram may be having API issues.

Comment: I just also got same problem since 18.00 MET

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the 302 redirect from hitting "api.instagram.com".

You should use the URLs:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getAuthUrl($state)
{
    return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase(
        'https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize', $state
    );
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getTokenUrl()
{
    return 'https://instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
}
```

Code was taken from overriding my Instagram Socialite plugin for Laravel. (socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/instagram/)

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue and it was due to a redirect from api.instagram.com to instagram.com. We removed the "api." from the beginning of the url (so https://instagram.com/oauth/access_token) and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

it probably doesn't matter which endpoint you will try

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token which redirect you on
https://instagram.com/oauth/access_token
or
https://instagram.com/oauth/access_token

Endpoint allow you only for POST request but for some reason it doesn't work properly. I have similar problem I was using method POST for a long time and now it also doesn't work. It's look like some Instagram API issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while using `Django==1.7.8` and `django-allauth==0.24.1`. I fixed it by changing the `access_token_url` and `authorize_url` to use `api.instagram.com` subdomains instead of just`instagram.com`.